# Retrieving related items in podio php

Tags: php, podio

My question concerns related items in Podio, I am using the library for PHP.

The setup is as follows:
I have one app where each item have related items.
How do I retrieve those related items? It's either a hasOne relation or a belongsto.

It isn't a field or I would have been able to retrieve the field id from the overview.

Can I retrieve related items?

Comment: Minor formatting fixes to get the format which you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the related (referenced) items, grouped by apps and sorted by title, by using the following call in the PHP sdk:

```
PodioItem::get_references( $item_id );
```

Related documentation can be found here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-references-22439